# Exact sequence multiplies an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

let $A,B,C$ be $R$-modules and $I\subset R$ be an ideal. Given that $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C\to 0$ is exact, do we have that $IA\xrightarrow{f'} IB\xrightarrow{g'} IC\to 0$ is exact? I have shown that $g'$ is surjective since $Im(g')=I\cdot Im(g)$. However, I have trouble showing that $\ker{g'}=I\cdot\ker{g}$. By definition $\ker{g'}=\{\sum i_k b_k\in IB: g'(\sum i_k b_k)=\sum i_k g(b_k)=0\}$, but this doesn't imply that $g(b_k)=0$. Any hints?

Comment: I think that $IM$ is naturally isomorphic to $I\otimes_R M$, so the theorem follows from the right exactness of tensor products.

Comment: @Compacto That's not true. You always have a surjective map $I \otimes M \to IM$, but that need not be injective.

Comment: The sequence need not to be exact. consider $I\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow R/I\longrightarrow 0$ and $I^2\longrightarrow I\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow0 $